# Contact data is not listing Data Extension created by entry event while making decision split

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

I built a journey following  below steps.

1. Create entry event using "Salesforce data" as entry source
2. Selected an object and chosen fire event whenever a record is created or updated.
3. Saved this entry event
4. The above steps generated a sendable data extension
5. I need to create a decision split now by selecting "Contact Data" and choosing the above generated sendable data extension.

However the sendable data extension generated by entry event is not available in "Contact Data" menu in Journey Builder. Why is it not available? Do I need to map it in Contact Builder?

I tried to map it in contact builder using the below steps

1. I went to contact builder tab
2. Created a attribute group called "TestJourney"
3. Tried to map the Contact Key with Lead Id of DE
4. I got below Error

   **Error : You cannot link data attributes using text attributes with a length of -1. This limit ensures queries can accurately return information**

   5. I checked datatype of Lead ID and found this to be "Text Datatype". As the contact Key is also a text datatype, I shouldnt be getting this error while mapping. [image: Error while trying to Map the DE generated by Entry event of journey with the Contact Key in contact builder]

Please explain why this is happening!

Answer (score 0):

have you mapped that data extension in contact builder after it's created.
although marketing cloud automatically creates the data extension, you still need to map it in contact builder or in population depending on your need

Comment: did it workerd?

Comment: Thanks Shivam. i did try to map it in contact builder using below teps 

1. Created an attribute group naned "test"
2. Clicked on Link data extension and selected DE created automatically by entry event of Journey builder
3. Tried to link Contact Key and Lead ID (both are of same data types), but I could see the below error and am not able to link it to the contact Key in contact builder. What could be the reason ? 
  
Error : You cannot link data attributes using text attributes with a length of -1. This limit ensures queries can accurately return information.

Comment: i did the exact same steps for account object being fetched from salesforce. Can you please check the data extension and properties of the lead id field once.

Comment: Data type for Lead ID is Text and I hope the contact key is also a text data type. So ideally when i map these both there shouldn't be any problem with Linkage.

Comment: Anyone could help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The data you are to be using in your decision split, should be available as Event Data in decision split, just like Gender in my example here below:
[image: decision split with Salesforce data].

You should remember to select it as Entry Data in your Entry Event, in order for you to use it in decision split.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating relationship with text data type fields the length of the field shud be below 256, If more than 256 we will get that error